# Preserving Element Order when Extracting Unique Values from a Python List

Tags: python

I have a Python list where the order of the elements is crucial to me. I want to extract only the unique elements from the list while maintaining their original order. I initially attempted using the set() function, but I discovered that it doesn't preserve the order of elements.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
my_list = [5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
# After extraction, I want the result to be: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this in Python? I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to achieve the desired outcome. Thank you!